# RestSharp AddJsonBody serialization camel case

Tags: asp.net-core, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp v107.1.1 in a .net 5.0 core web app and when i add an object to my RestRequest with AddJsonBody it's serializing the property names in camel casing.

How do i make RestSharp not modify the property names when serializing!?

```
request.AddJsonBody(new { IHateCamelCase = "why you do this!" });
```

results in

```
CONTENT <root type="object">   <iHateCamelCase type="string">why you do this!</iHateCamelCase> </root>
```

when it should look like this

```
CONTENT <root type="object">   <IHateCamelCase type="string">why you do this!</iHateCamelCase> </root>
```

An example would be great!

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure the serializer as you would do with anything else.

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.General);
client.UseSystemTextJson(options);
```

Comment: You deleted my post but left your comment. Did you know multi billion dollar companies recommend RestSharp as a sub vendor? There exists an inferred large and big money customer base. Unfortunately you don’t get any of the $, which is a downside of open source

Comment: I didn't delete your comment; I am unable to do it. I can only delete my own comments, and I did that as it became meaningless. I do know about what you mentioned, but I don't think it's the general OSS downside. I observe this way more within the .NET ecosystem, compared with other stacks. RestSharp org on GitHub is set up for sponsorship, but the only corporate sponsor it has is AWS, which doesn't use RestSharp. Anyway, that's beyond the topic of the question. I understand the concern about breaking changes. However, major changes today follow the RFC process.